# Detect check_box_tag change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

### Is there a way to detect wether a checkbox is selected or deselected?

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can evaluate when a checkbox is selected/deselected without refreshing the page, using a form, AJAX, or JavaScript.

```
= check_box_tag "checkbox", nil, true
```

---

I'm looking for a solution that is something like this. Something similar to onChange in JavaScript will run when the checkbox is selected/unselected. The code below is just an example. I know it doesn't work.

```
= check_box_tag "checkbox, nil, selected == true ? "Selected" : "Deselected"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send a request to the server in order to make the user attributes change.

For example, you can attach an onChange event on jquery and send an AJAX request with checked param set to current value.

This is how your on change event might look like:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    checkboxValue = this.val();
    // Send AJAX with checkboxValue
});
```

Then on the controller you can set the @user attribute as you wish.

Comment: There isn't a way that I can evaluate a line if a user checks or unchecks the box? @user.update_column(:boolean, true) works. I just want to attach it to the box's condition without using a form, JavaScript, or AJAX.

Comment: No ;) you cannot run server-side code on the client side. You have to send a request to the server to make the update.

Comment: @user.update_column(:boolean, true) updates the column and does exactly what I want it to do. I am looking for a way to run that code when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear as to what I am trying to achieve.